# Move inside a particular directory without knowing its name

Tags: java, file

I want to move inside a directory in Java but I don't know its name? Does Java provide any functionality to do so?

```
File srcFile = "C:/Entertainment/XXXXXXX/break.avi"
```

I am certain that there is only one directory inside Entertainment but I don't know its name. How can I move inside XXXXXXX directory to access any file inside it?

Any help?

Comment: You can get a list of files inside `Entertainment` that are directories.  If there's only one, then you'll have only one element in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
File file = new File("C:/Entertainment");
File[] files = file.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
File srcDir = new File("C:/Entertainment/");
File srcFile = null;
for (File dirMember : srcDir.listFiles()) {
    if (!dirMember.isDirectory()) {
        continue; // we don't need regular files
    }
    if (dirMember.getName().equals(".")) {
        continue; // we don't need this directory
    }
    if (dirMember.getName().equals("..")) {
        continue; // we don't need the parent directory
    }
    // This is the one you need.
    srcFile = new File(new File(srcDir, dirMember.getName()), "break.avi");
}
```

You could also use a FileFilter, e.g one from [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)

```
File dir = new File("C:/Entertainment/");
File[] files = dir.listFiles( DirectoryFileFilter.INSTANCE ); // returns all subdirs
srcFile = new File(files[0], "break.avi");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File srcFile = new File("C:\\Entertainment");
srcFile = new File(srcFile, srcFile.list()[0]);
srcFile = newFile(srcFile, "break.avi");
System.out.println(srcFile.getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    File outer= new File("C:/test");
    File inner = outer.listFiles()[0];//if you are sure there is one
    File[] listOfFilesInInnerMost = inner.listFiles();
    System.out.println("Files: " + Arrays.asList(listOfFilesInInnerMost));
```

will print

> Files: [C:\test\something\text (2).txt, C:\test\something\text (3).txt, C:\test\something\text.txt]